# Ember Serve can't access on provided host/port. No errors

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Really not certain what I'm doing wrong here. I'm trying to figure out Ember and can't seem to access anything on the provided host/files. There is no errors aside from watchman, which I'm fairly certain isn't necessary to get this working.

```
vagrant@homestead:/Users/me/Code/ember-serve$ ember serve

Could not start watchman
Visit https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
Livereload server on http://localhost:49153
Serving on http://localhost:4200/

Build successful - 18390ms.



Slowest Nodes (totalTime => 5% )              | Total (avg)         
----------------------------------------------+---------------------
Babel (16)                                    | 14536ms (908 ms)    
Concat (8)                                    | 1411ms (176 ms)
```

But http://localhost:4200/ can never be reached.

Ember was initialized inside of ember-serve successfully with no errors. Can't seem to find many other people having this issue. Changing the port makes no difference. My hosts file is correct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by adding the following to my VagrantFile. Fact that it was a virtual host was the issue, since I wasn't accessing the proper localhost.

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 4200, host: 4200, auto_correct: true
```